# I want to install closure compiler on Ubuntu but don't know how to include new packages in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, compiler

I want to include new universe saucy packages, but I don't know how to do this. Please help me out.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You mention "saucy" but have tagged with "12.04". Are you asking about how to install universe packages in 13.10? Are you asking about how to submit new packages to the Ubuntu repository? Are you asking about how to backport newer packages to an older Ubuntu release?

Comment: Possible dupe [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure is not available in Ubuntu 12.04. You need to upgrade or install Ubuntu 14.04. Closure was available in Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy) but 13.10 is not LTS and will soon be completely unsupported.